# Is there any way to store non NSCoding compliant objects in a NSManagedObject attribute?

Tags: ios, core-data

As the title says is there any way for this to be done? This is due to me using an apple class (MCSession) which is not NSCoding compliant.

Edit: I've now realised what I asked was silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not, and you should stop and ask yourself why you are trying to do it in the first place. Core Data has certain "native" types that it likes to store, and you should stick to them. Doing otherwise is a big waste, because the object is archived (turned into an NSData — that is why it must conform to NSCoding) and stored as a binary "blob" (which means that it is not searchable or indexable and takes up a lot of space).